# List all files attached to a user story

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfvc

When DEV checks in files into TFS 2017 they tie that check in to a user story and I can see the changeset/s on the user stories.  How can I run a query/report/sql command or use a program to see all the files that were changed for a user story?

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing built in that does that. What are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: A lot of files (reports, classic asp) have to be manually be deployed until we figure out an auto-deploy process for these files, so instead of DEV listing out files they changed I was hoping since we've migrated to use TFS for our entire SDLC and they attach they're check-ins to user stories I could just tap into that to get the files they changed so they don't have to list them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the ArtifactLink:

```
Get http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=All&api-version=3.2
```

Check the example of the api's response:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Looks like I'll have to hook into the api, cube, or sql commands to get the information I need.  I've worked very little with using api's so I'll have to research setting something like this up.

Comment: You could refer to this example: https://github.com/redarrowlabs/vsts-restapi-samplecode/blob/master/VSTSRestApiSamples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItems.cs.